# Selenium IWebElement to PhantomJSWebElement

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, ghostdriver

Im using Ghost Driver (PhantomJS) in my C# project. I have a question.
Selenium has PhantomJSWebElement and PhantomJSDriver.
Im creating PhantomJSDriver

```
PhantomJSDriverService service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.IgnoreSslErrors = true;
service.LoadImages = false;
service.Start();
PhantomJSDriver ghostDriver = new PhantomJSDriver(service);
```

And then trying to find elements by xpath

```
List<string> retVal = new List<string>();
var aElements = ghostDriver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[@id='menu']//a[@href]");
foreach(PhantomJSWebElement link in aElements)
{
   try
   {
      retVal.Add(link.GetAttribute("href"));
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
      continue;
   }
}
```

So i have an error while casting `IWebElemet` to `PhantomJSWebElement`.

```
PhantomJSWebElement el = (PhantomJSWebElement)link;
```

also not works (throwing casting exception). So the question is, how to get PhantomJSWebElement by PhantomJSDriver returns only IWebElement (or a collection of them) while finding.

Comment: This question is hard to answer without you posting the exact exception text.  Also, have you stepped through this exception with your debugger yet?  What `type` is `link`?

Comment: I have russian version on VS. Text is: Не удалось привести тип объекта "OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement" к типу "OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS.PhantomJSWebElement".It throws at PhantomJSWebElement link in aElements

Comment: I presume that `link` is of type `WebElement`.  `PhantomJSWebElement` inherits from `RemoteWebElement`.  Have you tried casting like this:  `PhantomJSWebElement el = (RemoteWebElement)link;` instead?

Comment: Where is no WebElement. PhantomJSWebElement inherits from RemoteWebElement

Comment: Double casting like (PhantomJSWebElement)(RemoteWebElement) has the same exception.

Comment: Documentation has example but it not works to. `    driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
    PhantomJSWebElement elem = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
    elem.SendKeys("Cheese please!");`

Comment: Please link the URL to the example you are following.

Comment: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html goto PhantomJSWebElement class documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should not be using the browser-specific classes when using the .NET bindings. Instead, you should be coding to the interfaces that you expect. This allows you to substitute in different implementations as needed. Your code would look something like this:

```
PhantomJSDriverService service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.IgnoreSslErrors = true;
service.LoadImages = false;

// Not sure I'd use Start here. The constructor will start the service
// for you.
service.Start();

// Use the IWebDriver interface. There's no real advantage to using
// the PhantomJSDriver class.
IWebDriver ghostDriver = new PhantomJSDriver(service);

// ...

List<string> retVal = new List<string>();
var aElements = ghostDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='menu']//a[@href]"));

// Use the IWebElement interface here. The concrete PhantomJSWebElement
// implementation gives you no advantages over coding to the interface.
foreach(IWebElement link in aElements)
{
    try
    {
        retVal.Add(link.GetAttribute("href"));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

You should also note that there is every possibility that the class documentation is incorrect. Knowing the source code for the language bindings, the `PhantomJSWebElement` class is never actually instantiated anywhere. I believe what you're actually getting back from your `FindElements()` call are `RemoteWebElements`, so attempting to cast them down the inheritance hierarchy to the more specific subclass is doomed to failure.